# separation of logic and UI in titanium (javascript)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, business-logic, titanium

i'm new to appcelerators titanium and javascript and i'm interested in coding an iphone app. i recognized that there is a need of "many" code for creating the UI. that's no problem so far, but i tend to separate that code from my application logic wisely. what are the best practices?

**[update]** [tweetanium](https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium/tree/master/mobile/Tweetanium) is a great example how to structure a titanium mobile application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i just found a cool practice.

i include the con_file.js with the application logic the view_file.js with

```
Titanium.include('../controller/con_file.js');
```

now i'm able to access the hole data structure.

Comment: You could also try commonJS: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Mobile+Best+Practices

Answer (score 4):

i'll have a try:

i tend to use the [mvc-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) for developing my application since implementing all stuff in one single js-file is quite ugly. so i decided to use one file for the view and all the stuff concering the look-and-feel, one file for the database handling (the controller), especially the sql-statements, and one file for the [abstract data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (the model).

a short example:

*view:* viewConcerningObject.js

```
Ti.include('object.js');

var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var myObject = new object();

var myObjectName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
   text:myObject.getName();
});

win.add(myObjectName);
```

*model:* object.js

```
Ti.include('controllerConceringObject.js');

function object(){
   this.name = 'myInitialName';

   this.getName(){
      return this.name;
   };

   this.setName(newName){
      this.name = newName;
   };

   this.updateNameFromDb(){
      this.name = getNameFromDatabase();
   };

}
```

*controller:* controllerConcerningObject.js

```
function getNameFromDataBase(){
   var db = Ti.Database('objects');
   var sql = 'SELECT name FROM objects';
   var recordset = db.execute(sql);
   var name  = recordset.field(0);
   recordset.close();
   db.close();
   return name;
};
```

so the folder structure could be like this:

myProject: folderView(viewConcerningObject.js), folderModel(theDatabase.db,object.js), folderController(controllerConcerningObject.js).