# JavaScript library/framework for Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium

I've just took my first steps in mobile development with Titanium Mobile. Coming from PHP and JavaScript programming for the web, I'm really missing two things:

1. A JavaScript library
2. A MVC or similar "framework" to effectively separate logic and design

1.
I've been googling around and cannot seem to find a good answer. I tried taking the parts from MooTools that I wanted, but that didn't really work because, and this is where almost all JS libraries fail, even the core parts require window/navigator/dom, etc. I guess this could be done manually, but that doesn't sound like a future-proof way to go.

Does someone know a good library that bundles some of the most-used functions or, even better, know how to get MooTools core to work in Titanium?

2.
Something that simplifies writing nice, structured code for Titanium Mobile. I could do this manually and I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675611/separation-of-logic-and-ui-in-titanium-javascript), but I'm looking for something/someone that already found the best way to do this :) and maybe even wrote a bit of code which could be re-used.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I came from a PHP background as well but I'm still finding it easiest to just write my own objects and extend them as necessary. If you're looking for something like jQuery then look no further then the Titanium API. The closest you'll come to an MVC like feel is using event listeners to fire custom events page to page so you can separate the UI/logic.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Could you explain further what you mean with the event listeners? I don't quite see the link between firing events and separated UI/logic.

Comment: I might be completely wrong but I find firing a custom event from my page with UI(view) elements is similar to $this->view->var because I can fire the event with data to a listener(controller) and go from there. It's not a perfect replacement but I've found it as close to an MVC feel as I can get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Tweetanium](https://github.com/appcelerator/tweetanium), an example project that demonstrates best practices in Titanium including how to stucture your code.

Also be sure to check out [this](http://blog.krawaller.se/titanium-application-structure-learning-from) blog post concerning Tweetanium. The author dissects the code and points out some of the advantages of the approach used.

[Here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/01/tweetanium-mobile.html) is Appcelerator's original blog post on Tweetanium.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I started coding a similar setup after my post. It looks like the general direction is good, but I'll be sure to use some of the practices they used with Tweetanium.

Comment: :-( I tried to check out Tweetanium two days ago, and it looks like Appcelerator hasn't kept it up-to-date: it wouldn't run in the current SDK.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, but you don't really need to be able to run the app so long as you can read the code.