# Titanium Appcelerator - Multi Screen Application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have some experience in BB app development. But, I'm pretty much new to the Titanium Appcelerator Studio.

I did some googling on the appcelerator stuff and I know that there are many sample apps using tabs openly available and I was able to create one tab based app including some commonly used UI features such as list views,views, windows, and functionality such as camera feature, geo location etc.

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is to create a multiple screen app without the use of tabs in it. That being said, I'm trying to create an MVC kind of framework in which I can split up the views and data models. I found some samples for this like Tweetanium. -https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium
https://github.com/smontgomerie/Appcelerator-on-Rails

But I feel that, it's quite big for a newbie in appcelerator. So, Is there any sample project that I can use as a reference and build my application on top of it ?

Also, any links to some helpful sites like [separation of logic and UI in titanium (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675611/separation-of-logic-and-ui-in-titanium-javascript/3676461#3676461) or useful tips will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Since you're planning to use MVC, then please go through http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework

Comment: Go to Alloy. It gives you inbuilt MVC structure when you create the new project.

Comment: Thx for the quick response!! Ok, will go through it.
So if we have to follow MVC pattern we should go for alloy and  can't use classic ??

Comment: You can do the MVC in Classic also, but its more complicated as compared to Alloy. In classic you have to maintain all the folder structure for MVC. Please follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start

Comment: Thanks guys !! Will try alloy framework for sure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 good examples of MVC applications using Alloy that are available to you.

This one is great because you can download the actual app for IOS and Android to follow along with.  If I remember correctly it is using custom tabs.
https://github.com/appcelerator/Codestrong

The other, which is closer to what you were looking for is Field-Service-App.  This example doesn't use tabs, but does have a nav bar that controls the app at the top and switches between list and detail screens.
https://github.com/appcelerator/Field-Service-App

These examples will show you methods of separating the logic from the presentation just like you are asking for.  They will also show you custom font and if you get into it enough, the Field-Service-App works with Appcelerator's cloud solution if setup properly.

Comment: Thanks mate ! Let me go through these sample apps.